# Showing that a map between surfaces is a local isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Currently studying Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces.

We have:
$$\sigma:(0,\infty) × \mathbb{ R} \to \mathbb{R}^3, \quad  (u,v) \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (u \cos v,u\sin v ,u)$$

We need to show that $\phi$ is a local isometry from $\sigma$ to $\sigma ' $
where $$\phi: (0, \infty) × \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2, \quad (u,v)\to (u\cos(v/\sqrt{2}),u\sin(v/\sqrt{2}))$$
where $\sigma': \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3, (x,y) \to (x,y,0)$

The answers say you need to compare the first fundamental form of $\sigma$ with the first fundamental form of the composition
$\sigma ' \circ \phi $

I was wondering why you have to do this?
I get comparing the first fundamental forms but why do we choose to compose those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why you have to do this?

Because you want to prove that $\phi$ is a local isometry, and the definition of local isometry requires the 1st fundamental form of the domain to be equal to the *pullback* of the 1st fundamental form of the target. The target is $\sigma'$. Pullback means composition  with $  \phi$. There is not much to say here other than review the definition of local isometry.

Comment: Get it now I think! σ:(0,∞)×R→R3
ϕ:(0,∞)×R→R2
σ′:R2→R3,(x,y)→(x,y,0) therefore the composition of σ′o ϕ makes σ? Thanks for your help!!